No consigo hacer robocopy con una dirección con espacios
Estoy intentando hacer un robocopy donde la dirección contiene espacios. (Ej: F:\Bases de datos\...
La sentencia es:
robocopy %latest_diff_path% %LOCAL_DIRECTORY_LASTDIFF% %latest_diff% /xo /V

El latest_diff_path es la dirección que tiene los espacios.
He probado lo siguiente:

Poner comillas en el robocopy tanto solo al %latest_diff_path% como a las dos direcciones y archivo. NO FUNCIONA
He hecho un: set "latest_diff_path="%%~dpA"" y un echo con el latest_diff_path para corroborar que a la dirección ya le aplicaba las comillas antes del robocopy y sí lo hacía. Hago el robocopy y NO FUNCIONA.

No sé cómo hacerlo ya, no puedo poner la dirección exacta con las comillas en vez de la variable, ya que nunca será la misma. ESO SÍ FUNCIONARÍA.

¿Has probado a poner las variables entre comillas? Por ejemplo robocopy "%latest_diff_path%" "%LOCAL_DIRECTORY_LASTDIFF%" "%latest_diff%" /xo /V. De esa manera debería funcionarte.
